# Android store app release. Delete original app then replace with same named app with different keystore?

Tags: android, google-play

Is it possible to delete an app from the Android store we developed, since we lost the original keystore, and then publish a new app to the store with the same "com.myname.myappname" but with a different signed certificate/keystore?

Would the app update for the user? Or would they just get a warning the app can't be updated, or what happens?

Comment: Package adress is locked forever. Apps are locked forever, can't be deleted... don't know if maybe with emails to Google addressing some issues. Upload a new version, with new keystore, new package but with same name... no issue with that. Change old app name for other.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. Read the documentation: [Publishing Updates on Android Market](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketupgrade)

> Before uploading the updated application, be sure that you have incremented the android:versionCode and android:versionName attributes in the <manifest> element of the manifest file. Also, the package name must be the same and **the .apk must be signed with the same private key. If the package name and signing certificate do not match those of the existing version, Market will consider it a new application and will not offer it to users as an update.**